# Web script to get the properties of the document

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco, freemarker

Create a web script to get the parameters of the document in java Example url:

```
localhost:8080/alfresco/s/get-document-data?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/3b3597e5-b5ec-41d5-b63b-54b050dccd1b&property=cm:name
```

As a result the script should return Json object of a kind:

```
{
"nodeRef": "workspace: // SpacesStore / 3b3597e5-b5ec-41d5-b63b-54b050dccd1b",
"value": "value property - the one we got from nodRef"
}
```

Create a web script to retrieve all subfolder settings along the way. Please help!

DocumentScript.java

```
import org.activiti.engine.impl.util.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.impl.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DocumentScript extends AbstractWebScript {
    public static JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    @Override
    public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res)  throws IOException {
        try {
            String noderef = req.getParameter("nodeRef");
            String valueRef = res.getEncodeResourceUrlFunction("value");
            obj.put("nodeRef", noderef);
            obj.put("value", valueRef);
            String jsonString = obj.toString();
            res.getWriter().write(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new WebScriptException("Unable to serialize JSON");

        }
    }
}
```

document-script-context.xml

```
<bean class="alfresco.extension.templates.webscripts.repository.DocumentScript"
      parent="templates.webscripts.repository">
</bean>
```

document-script.get.desc.xml

```
<webscript>
    <shortname>Documents</shortname>
    <description>JSON data
    </description>
    <url>/script-document?q={keyword}</url>
    <authentication>user</authentication>
    <format default="html"/>
    <family>Alfresco Script</family>
</webscript>
```

document-script.get.html.ftl

```
{
"obj" : [
<#list obj as Obj>
    {
    "nodeRef" : "${Obj.nodeRef}",
    "value" : "${Obj.value}"
    }
    <#if Obj_has_next>,</#if>
</#list>
]
}
```

Here I want to get the parameters of the document here is the code but it doesn't work, what's wrong with it?

```
06220015 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06220002 Error during processing of the template 'The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> obj [in template "repository/document-script.get.html.ftl" at line 3, column 8] Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)?? The failing instruction: ==> #list obj as Obj [in template "repository/document-script.get.html.ftl" at line 3, column 1]'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by creating a class for the JSON object then just do something like this:

```
String url = localhost:8080/alfresco/s/get-document-data?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/3b3597e5-b5ec-41d5-b63b-54b050dccd1b&property=cm:name;
String[] values = url.split('?');
String[] value = values[0].split('=');
jsonObject.setNodeRef(value[1]);
.....
```

This will work if you know that your url has the exact same parameters you mentioned. Just use regexp. I haven't tested the code myself, give it a try.

Comment: The URL (String url = localhost:8080/alfresco/s/get-document-data?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/3b3597e5-b5ec-41d5-b63b-54b050dccd1b&property=cm:name;) must not be spelled out in the code, it must be entered in the address bar in the browser.